# Can I still add friends to Game Center on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, game-center

My iPhone and my daughter's iPod both have iOS 9. I have tried to add her as a friend in Game Center using both her email address and her nickname. But nothing seems to work.

She has also sent a request to me. But nothing seems to get through.

I have read that game center does not allow adding friends in iOS 10. Does that mean it also doesn't work I iOS 9 now?

Note: my daughter is under 13 and we have entered her age as such. That does kind of limitations in some games. But I had not heard that it would block her from using Game Center friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Game Center's features were removed from the Game Center service itself so they still wouldn't work, including adding friends, even if you have Ios 9 (and in Ios 10 obviously).
Now, you  can see just the rankings and the goals of the game; you can also invite and challenge your friends only through iMessage, and only if the game supports it.

Comment: Dang. That means there is no way to play dragonvale with my daughter....